# Easel is unable to clone bmp in recursive clone of a container

Tags: createjs

Using EaselJS v 1.0.0, when images are preloaded using the LoadQueue, it looks like they cannot be cloned during a recursive clone on a parent container.

For example:

```
function test() {

  const { Bitmap, Container, LoadQueue, Shape, Stage, Ticker } = createjs

  function loadImage () {
    const queue = new LoadQueue()
    queue.addEventListener("fileload", addImage)
    queue.loadFile("image.jpg")
  }

  function addImage (e) {
    const image = e.result

    const bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(image)
    const cnt = new Container()
    cnt.addChild(bmp)

    const cnt2 = cnt.clone(true)
    cnt2.x = 200

    mainCnt.addChild(cnt, cnt2)

    stage.update()
  }

  const stage = new Stage(document.getElementById('test'))
  const mainCnt = stage.addChild(new Container())

  loadImage()
}
```

The above results in an async GET fail when it tries to do a cloneNode in Bitmap's clone method on this line in EaselJS#Bitmap.js:

```
image = image.cloneNode();
```

This results in an async error when it runs image.cloneNode() on an  node where the src is a blob.

I can work around this with caching each time I need it, but I'm updating a fairly large repository of games (hundreds) build on Easel 0.6 with quite a number of instances like this.

Anyone know of any workarounds for this?

Comment: Bug filed for EaselJS - https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/949

Workaround, if container content is static, is to cache the container and use the cached version.

Comment: This is indeed a bug. Ongoing discussion is happening on the issue URL provided by Adrian.